# Google Play Console: An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (7C089B92)

Tags: google-play-console

When I click the Start roll-out to Alpha, I get this error:

An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (7C089B92)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6Yxt.png)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6Yxt.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Tell something about your project and what you already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: same to me. Even if the error occurs, it seems that the bundle is processed and under review. But in my case the new version is under review already 4 days...

Comment: @Marco Are you new to Google Play Console like me? I also found 11 app-related warning messages, could the problem be related to that?